# using <UIAutomation.h> SDK 7.0A in Windows10

Tags: c++, windows-10, visual-studio-2005, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm having trouble compiling a piece of software that uses UIAutomation in Windows 10.
The problem: I need to compile a UI-lib against Win SDK 7.0A - and I can't find a way to install the SDK in Win10. (Note: using Visual Studio 2005)

The single line of code that caueses trouble:

`#include <UIAutomation.h>`

As I've had trouble installing the SDK I've just copied everything I could find from my Win7 machine, but that doesn't seem to work either.
In Project settings / Linker / Additional Include Directories I've set `$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\UIAutomationCore.lib` - just like in Win7 (and I've ensured the files are there as well)

Long story short - I just can't get it to compile.

Has anyone successfully compiled against SDK 7.0A from Win10 yet? / Important: I really do need to compile using 7.0A to maintain platform compatibility. (so using a newer SDK isn't really an option)

thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: Visual Studio 2005? Maybe 2015? Also I have no trouble including `#include <UIAutomation.h>` targeting 10.0.14393.0 SDK. Note that you don't really need dedicated 7.0A sdk to build application for Windows 7.

Comment: No, sadly really VS2005 - and I cannot change that, at least for that special project. what do you mean with I don't need 7.0A SDK - is it possible to build the app with 10.X SDK and run it on Win7?

Comment: Also I should mention: the target system resides in a quite "secure" environment and cannot easily be updated (so no installing of a newer windows SDK, vcredist, whatsoever - so VC8 it is..)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to build app with 10.x SDK and run it on Win7. However I'm not sure whether it is possible to use Windows 7 or Windows 10 SDKs with VS 2005.

Comment: Thanks, will try asap - I've been using SDK 7.0A with VS2005 for quite a while :-)